# Do i need to release NSMutableDictionary in this case?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsmutabledictionary

Do I need to release `dictCellCollectionIndividual` in this case?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

... ...
... ...
... ...

    // Local declaration of dictCellCollectionIndividual
    NSMutableDictionary *dictCellCollectionIndividual;

    // Copy the specific dictionary from dictCellCollection to dictCellCollectionIndividual. dict CellCollection is declared elsewhere.
    dictCellCollectionIndividual = [dictCellCollection objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayCellCollectionOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

... ...
... ...
... ...

// Do I need to release?
[dictCellCollectionIndividual release];

return cell;
```

}

Doesn't using `objectForKey` increase the retain count? Don't I have to release it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it simply returns a pointer to the object held within the dictionary; if you plan to keep the object around for any period of time, you need to take ownership of it, so that the object will remain valid if `NSDictionary` is deallocated in the meantime. In this case, you'll need to make sure to either `release` or `autorelease` the object when you're done with it. If you're planning to use it only as a temporary value (say, as an argument to an `NSLog` call), it's probably unnecessary to retain the object, and therefore unnecessary to release it.